# How do I remove the dotted lines on a TreeView?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, radtreeview

You'll notice on the RadTreeView [main page for Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) that the TreeView example has no dotted lines.

[image]

There are no lines connecting the nodes to their parents. However, on all of the "Functionality" pages (on the lefthand navigation), every single one of the examples contains lines.

[image]

How do I get rid of those dotted lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do to hide the dotted lines is to set the **ShowLineImages** property to **false**. You can see the following help article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-appearance-line-images.html.

Best regards,
Rumen